# EF Core Include partially populated informations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a web API which is able to show some details about behaviors of an user.

When we call `api/behaviors/5` for example, we call the `ActionResult GetBehavior(int id)` from my BehaviorsController.

In the Model Behavior, I have an `public virtual User User { get; set; }` variable which I use to provide information from the User on the Behaviors/Details View of my web application which call my API, like the User Surname for example.

To do so, I wrote this method in my `BehaviorsController` :

```
// GET: api/Behaviors/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Behavior>> GetBehavior(int id)
    {
        var behavior = await 
            _context
            .Behaviors
            .Include(b => b.User)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Id == id);

        if (behavior == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return behavior;
    }
```

It works really great, but I have a security issue ; in the `User` Model I have a `Password` property, which is used, especially, when I create a new User.

the problem is that the password, even if its hashed, is sent back by the api if I use the `.Include(b => b.User)`

So I'm looking for the piece of Linq code which can populate the `User` variable of the `Behavior` model with only the necessary informations. I tried this one :

```
// GET: api/Behaviors/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Behavior>> GetBehavior(int id)
    {
        var behavior = await 
            _context
            .Behaviors
            .Include(b => new User
            {
                Id = b.User.Id,
                Name = b.User.Name
            })
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Id == id);

        if (behavior == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return behavior;
    }
```

But this returns me the following error :

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: The expression 'new Behavior() {Id = p.User.Id, Name = p.User.Name}' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty').

I'm not able to understand properly this error. What can I do to populate my `User` with only some informations ?

Comment: Include is used for eager loading, not for selective property projection. Change the .Include to a .Select. You should also consider not leaking your DB entities out of a WebApi - eg create new api Poco classes for serialization

Comment: Thanks for the advice ! I already wrote my Poco classes, the code is from the api and I totally modified my object. I'm actually not using any class called "Behavior". Anyway, I'm not able to merge a the Select with the Include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `User` entity (class) add `[JsonIgnore]` before the password property:

Example:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public string password {get; set;}
```

For `[JsonIgnore]` to work you need to add the following using at top:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
```

Or if you are using Newtonsoft:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

**EDIT:**
Best practice is not to return the `User` itself and create a `UserDto` class which is kind of the same with `User` but it has no password property and if you like you can even add extra info in it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution ! Would it has an impact of any kind on the User Creation or else ?

Comment: @M.Ozn No... It will only ignore the password property while creating the json return. Password is actually there but it doesn't sent it to frontend.

Comment: @M.Ozn Use Newtonsoft. It seems if you use the System.Text.Json.Serialization it ignores the password feild even when it receives it at the backend. Newtonsoft does not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Include` is not for changing projection but instruction which entities to load and usually it is not needed if you have custom projection - your situation.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Behavior>> GetBehavior(int id)
{
    var behavior = await 
        _context
        .Behaviours
        .Select(b => new Behavior 
        { 
           Id = b.Id,
           ...
           User = new User
           {
              Id = b.User.Id,
              Name = b.User.Name
           }
        })
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Id == id);

    if (behavior == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return behavior;
}
```

Comment: This solution involves that I have to to recreate manually the Behavior Object. Is there an easier way to do this using Linq ? I have several Include/ThenInclude I didn't wrote on my example. Couldn't I just impact the User returned from the EF Include

Comment: Other solutions are workarounds. Usually you have to do that once and not returning model via network, but via DTO class which usually have less fields. Includes loads full entities with overhead to SQL Server. So better write that mapping once.